# Java switch smart enough to rearrange?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit

Given a hot piece of code that has switch with many case options (and all are with breaks e.g. can be rearranged) will JVM figure out the frequent entries to check them ahead of others?

Comment: It will usually generate a jump table, so the question of 'check them ahead of others' doesn't even arise.

Comment: So no, if we have a switch with 100s of cases we better implement a data structure that will do this (and even then its up to performance tests if this is worth the time)...

Comment: **No**. The *compiler* will *generate* the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency or likelihood of execution of individual cases doesn't come into it.  The compiler will generate either:

- a `tableswitch` instruction with an associated jump table that is indexed directly by the switch value, or
- a `lookupswitch` instruction with a table of key/target pairs that can (typically) be binary-searched.

See the [JVM Specification #3.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10).

Comment: This is true for `javac` compiler. But since there is `jit` tag in the question, OP might be also interested in how this works when JIT-compiler kicks in. HotSpot compiler treats `tableswitch` and `lookupswitch` similarly, and it **does** take into account **frequency statistics** collected during method profiling stage.

Comment: @apangin so in short if my Nth case is very predictable it will be resolved faster? like what branch prediction does for if else?

Comment: @vach Yes, HotSpot *can* do this, though it is not guaranteed that it will do this in each particular case.